# When I compiled the lucene-solr,use "ant idea" to configure IntelliJ,Get the following error:

Tags: solr, ant, lucene

I'm not familiar with ant。
I geted The following error when i use "ant idea" 。
What do I do?

ant version:
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019

```
lucene-solr git:(master) ant idea
Buildfile: /Users/hubiao/java/lucene-solr/build.xml

resolve:

resolve:

ivy-availability-check:
[loadresource] Do not set property disallowed.ivy.jars.list as its length is 0.

-ivy-fail-disallowed-ivy-version:

ivy-fail:

ivy-configure:
[ivy:configure] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0 - 20141213170938 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = /Users/hubiao/java/lucene-solr/lucene/top-level-ivy-settings.xml

resolve:

ivy-availability-check:
[loadresource] Do not set property disallowed.ivy.jars.list as its length is 0.

-ivy-fail-disallowed-ivy-version:

ivy-fail:

ivy-configure:
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = /Users/hubiao/java/lucene-solr/lucene/top-level-ivy-settings.xml

resolve:
.....
```